# Get Feature Service syncCapabilities with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, json

I'm working on an ArcPy script to test layers. I have either an arcpy mapping module layer object, or a feature service URL as a text string. I wish to get the feature service's capabilities, in particular the syncCapabilities to ascertain if it's sync enabled.

I'm not sure what API to use. I assume you can import JSON in Python, and use it to get the capabilities? The REST API is not very day 1 noob friendly. I could not find a real working example in my context.

> "capabilities": "Create,Delete,Query,Sync,Update,Uploads,Editing"

My hack attempts to integrate it into Python results in failure

[ArcGIS REST API: Sync-enabled feature services](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/sync-enabled-feature-services.htm)

```
import arcpy
import json

URL = "https://services.myserver.com/ERmEceOGq5cHrItq/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA/FeatureServer/jobs/jf90d6386f7494cd59c024f749773fe7b"
print URL
{
    "syncCapabilities" : {
        "supportsSyncEnabled"
}
```

How do I get the true or false this back from this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the service capabilities from the info of the specific layer you want to edit. Assuming you only have one layer on your FeatureServer service, it would be the layer with the index 0.

Access the capabilities info through python like this:

```
import urllib2
import json

fs_url = "https://yourarcgisserver.com/arcgis/rest/services/service_name/FeatureServer/0?f=json"
response = urllib2.urlopen(fs_url)
res_json = json.load(response)

print res_json["capabilities"]

Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ArcGIS Python API to do this now: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/updating-feature-layer-properties/